# DynamicIpSecurity wrong redirect in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I configured my web application in Azure with the [DynamicIpSecurity](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/08/27/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/) feature like this :

```
      <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="Forbidden">
        <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="20" />
        <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="30" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="1000" />
      </dynamicIpSecurity>
```

**Edit:**
I also have custom pages for HttpErros :

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="403"/>
      <remove statusCode="500"/>
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/404.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="403" path="/403.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="/500.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
    </httpErrors>
...
</system.webServer>
```

But the problem that it redirects my application to Azure's slot URL like :

```
https://my-application__9fb0/403.html
```

While it should be

```
https://myapplication.com/403.html
```

Which is giving "The web page in unavailable".

Is there anyway to configure the redirect URL ? if not what should I do alternatively ?

Comment: The IIS.net documentation for Dynamic IP Restriction is available here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I found the solution which is I should write the absolute path instead of the relative one.

like :

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="403"/>
      <remove statusCode="500"/>
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="https://myapplication.com/404.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="403" path="https://myapplication.com/403.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="https://myapplication.com/500.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

Thank you NazimL for your answer it guides me to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

So the DIPR config is returning a 403 status, but seems like you have custom error page (403.html) and you haven't posted how that is configured for your site. If you don't mind sharing your site name, I can look into how this is configured for your site. You can follow instructions [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly) if you don't want to publicly share your site name.

Comment: Yes I have custom error configuration , I edited the post.